# php html multiple quotation marks invalid code

Tags: php, html, quotes

how can i make sure these quotation marks become valid in PHP?

```
<?
    echo "oaktree.addItem('test1<img src='img.png'>', branch1, '');";
    echo "oaktree.addItem('test2<img src='img.png'>', branch1, '');";
?>
```

the problem is in the  tag...
thanks

Comment: What error are you getting? That looks fine

Comment: when i remove the <img> tag, it displays the context, otherwise it just stays empty (the page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code is correct as far as PHP syntax is concerned, but it does not output correctly formatted JavaScript, as you are already aware. You can use double quotes inside double quotes in PHP as long as you escape them properly. You can do

```
<?
    echo "oaktree.addItem('test1<img src=\"img.png\">', branch1, '');";
    echo "oaktree.addItem('test2<img src=\"img.png\">', branch1, '');";
?>
```

Comment: Funny that this should be a downvote, I think you did not read the question well enough to justify that

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
echo <<<EOT
    oaktree.addItem('test1<img src="img.png">', branch1, '');
    oaktree.addItem('test2<img src="img.png">', branch1, '');
EOT;
?>
```